# Access to variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I do a console trace on the positionSlides method its showing slideShow as undefined.
How can this be when I clearly instantiate it in the document.ready callback. I also make sure to make this variable global so both the slideShow and the slideShowNavigation would have access to both these variables.

```
var slideShow, slideShowNavigation;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        slideShow = new SlideShow( $('#header #slideshow'), 980 );
        slideShowNavigation = new SlideShowNavigation( $('#header').find("#leftArrow"), $('#header').find("#rightArrow") );

    });


    // SLIDE SHOW CLASS
    function SlideShow( divContainer, slideWidth ){
        // Check to make sure a new instance is created
        if( ! (this instanceof SlideShow) ) return new SlideShow();

        this.$imageContainer = divContainer;
        this.slideWidth = slideWidth;
        var maxImages =     this.$imageContainer.children().length;

        this.getMaxSlides = function(){
            return maxImages;
        }

        this.positionSlides();

    }

    SlideShow.prototype.positionSlides = function(){
        console.log('imageContainer = '+slideShow);
    }

    SlideShow.prototype.update = function( dir ){

    }


    // ARROW NAVIGATION FOR SLIDESHOW

    function SlideShowNavigation( left, right){
        if( ! (this instanceof SlideShowNavigation) ) return new SlideShowNavigation();

        //this.updateArrows( slideShow.$imageContainer.find(":first") );

    }

    SlideShowNavigation.prototype.updateArrows = function( item ){

    }
```

Comment: As a small tip, use `console.log('imageContainer = ', slideShow)` (instead of a `+`), as Chrome will print this in a way that lets you look at the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
slideShow = new SlideShow( $('#header #slideshow'), 980 );
```

That line calls your `SlideShow` function, which calls `positionSlides()`, which looks for `slideShow`, but slideShow isn't defined until your `SlideShow` function returns.

Instead, in positionSlides() use `this` instead of `slideShow` to refer to the instance (this way your class is independent of the variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You have called positionSlides from the Slideshow constructor function.  The slideShow variable is not set until after that constructor function finishes.  So, you're accessing the slideShow global variable before it has been set in this part of positionSlides:

```
console.log('imageContainer = '+slideShow);
```

I'd suggest that in the positionSlides method, you could probably reference "this" instead of the global variable.

Change that line to:

```
console.log('imageContainer = ' + this);
```

As a suggestion, I find it a bit dangerous to use variable names that differ only in case `slideShow` (a global variable name) and `SlideShow` (a function name) and `slideshow` (a CSS identifier).  It makes your code harder to read and understand and it can be easy to inadvertently make a mistake.  In this case, I'd suggest the global variable be something like "theSlideShow" for increased readability and less likelihood of mistake.

Comment: Is there anywhere else you suggest to save a reference to both Instances instead of in a global variable scope. I don't like the idea of global either but not sure how else the objects would communicate between each other without using globals.

Comment: When you create the SlideShowNavigation object, give it a reference to the SlideShow object that it can store in it's own instance data.  No need to store that reference globally, it should be in the SlideShowNavigation instance data.  After all, a SlideShowNavigation object is only controlling one SlideShow, right?  So, the SlideShow instance could even be passed into the constructor of the SlideShowNavigation object or be set later via a method call.

Comment: Good idea but that doesn't seem good practice when it comes to slideshow needing access to SlideShowNavigation. slideshow doesn't need to depend on a navigation it could work on its own if needed to. But in this case in the update method I do a call to  SlideShowNavigation.updateArrows(). The only way I could think of was to make the references to both objects globally in order for that to happen.

Comment: This is a generic programming issue.  If you don't want the slideshow object to know anything about a navigation object, then you need to create an abstract event that you can fire from the slideshow object when it changes and the slideshow nav can watch that event and respond appropriately when it sees an event.

Comment: That's probably more work than required in this case.  Just create an instance variable in the slideshow object for a slideshow nav object.  Initialize it to null.  If you have a slideshow nav object, then tell the slideshow about it and the slideshow stores that in it's instance data.  When the slideshow makes a change, it can check for null and if the nav object is not null, then it calls it.  If it is null, it does nothing.

Comment: I agree in this case but I'm most lightly going to reuse this puppy for multiple types of navigation setups so I think I might implement the event system. Is there a custom built in event system in JS or you have to create your own.

Comment: @jfriend00 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1067/discussion-between-chapsterj-and-jfriend00)

Answer (score 0):

`slideShow` is not defined until the `SlideShow` function returns that definition. `SlideShow.positionSlides` is called before the constructor finishes.

Fix: call `positionSlides` only after `slideShow` has been defined.

```
var slideShow, slideShowNavigation;

    $(document).ready(function(){

        slideShow = new SlideShow( $('#header #slideshow'), 980 );
        slideShow.positionSlides();
        slideShowNavigation = new SlideShowNavigation( $('#header').find("#leftArrow"), $('#header').find("#rightArrow") );

    });


    // SLIDE SHOW CLASS
    function SlideShow( divContainer, slideWidth ){
        // Check to make sure a new instance is created
        if( ! (this instanceof SlideShow) ) return new SlideShow();

        this.$imageContainer = divContainer;
        this.slideWidth = slideWidth;
        var maxImages =     this.$imageContainer.children().length;

        this.getMaxSlides = function(){
            return maxImages;
        }

    }

    SlideShow.prototype.positionSlides = function(){
        console.log('imageContainer = '+slideShow);
    }

    SlideShow.prototype.update = function( dir ){

    }


    // ARROW NAVIGATION FOR SLIDESHOW

    function SlideShowNavigation( left, right){
        if( ! (this instanceof SlideShowNavigation) ) return new SlideShowNavigation();

        //this.updateArrows( slideShow.$imageContainer.find(":first") );

    }

    SlideShowNavigation.prototype.updateArrows = function( item ){

    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to pass the arguments when you call the constructor with `new` inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The SlideShow object calls the method `positionSlides` in its constructor:

```
this.positionSlides();
```

This method tries to access the variable that you are assigning itself to:

```
console.log('imageContainer = '+slideShow);
```

It doesn't exist yet because the constructor hasn't finished.

(edit - per discussion about relationships between the two objects)

"`SlideShow` needs to call methods of `SlideShowNavigation`" - done using events in Java.

You can use callbacks in javascript to create an event-driven model.

Suppose that `SlideShowNavigation` has a dependency of a `SlideShow` object, in the navigation. Also note the use of a single `options` object parameter, instead of individual parameters, this is a common construct because it simplifies parameter passing, resulting in more readable, more easily maintainable code. You don't risk breaking something if you add/remove a parameter since they are not positionally dependent this way.

```
function SlideShow() {
   // setup code

   this.onSomethingHappened=null;
}
SlideShow.prototype.doSomething() {
    // do something

    /// if a callback exists & is defined properly, then invoke it
    if (this.onSomethingHappened && 
            typeof this.onSomethingHappened==='function') {
        this.onSomethingHappened(this);
    }
}
SlideShow.prototype.publicMethod() {

}

function SlideShowNavigation(options){
    if( ! (this instanceof SlideShowNavigation) ) 
        return new SlideShowNavigation();

    this.slideShow = options.slideShow
    this.left = options.left;
    this.right = options.right;

    // bind to callbacks (events): assigning the `onSomethingHappened` property
    // of the SlideShow to a function in this object, which it will call at the
    // appropriate time

    this.slideShow.onSomethingHappened = this._somethingHappened;

     //this.updateArrows( slideShow.$imageContainer.find(":first") );

}

// i use an underscore to indicate a private method - since there's
// no way to create non-public prototype members. You can can 
// alternatively create private functions in the constructor though
// it's less memory efficient, and they are not directly accessible
// from prototype methods.

SlideShowNavigation.prototype._somethingHappened(e) {
    // e is the sender of the event
    ...
    // you can invoke methods of the sender directly using the ref passed here, 
    // if you like
    e.publicMethod();
}
```

Comment: Would be great if you could elaborate on what you consider a correct way to construct my code.

Comment: I don't really know what to say - you're trying to access the global target of an assignment of the object itself from within the object prototype. The object has no knowledge (and should not depend) on things outside of itself. It's appears to be just debugging code, so what are you trying to test for?

Comment: I just happened to put it in here. It probably makes more sense to debug it from the slideShowNavigation.updateArrows. Not sure how my code is crazy in any other way. But I could be wrong thats why I would love your opinion on how it would better make sense. I come from a java and AS3 background so i'm used to making classes of everything and then instantiating them as needed. Then having events do the communications between the classes. Please if you think it could be written differently and more standard, please give me an example of how it should be formatted.

Comment: Sorry - that was an overstatement and just a reaction to accessing the target of an object assignment from itself. (Removed :) For the relationship between SlideShow & SlideShowNavigation, I would think that you should have the SlideShowNavigation object require a SlideShow as a dependency (e.g. a constructor arguement) and maintain a reference internally, which frees you to use multiple instances as well.

Comment: Ah thanks good to know that i'm still within best practices. So you mean instead of making a global var for slideShow, instead keep it local to the document ready function and then pass a reference of slideshow as an argument parameter to the SlideShowNavigation constructor. This was also mentioned above by jfriend00 reply. What can I do when SlideShow needs to call methods of SlideShowNavigation. Slideshow doesn't need to always depend on SlideShowNavigation only for this setup. I usually use events for this in AS3 or java. Not sure what I should do in JS.

Comment: see edit for an example of how to create "events" in javascript (they are generally called callbacks in JS, but functionally the same)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are defining what slideshow is by calling the function Slideshow. That function calls positionSlides. This is called before the object is done constructing.